# React Native ios app is crashing with generic bu

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect, xcodebuild, xcode-build-settings

iOS app is built on react native running successfully on emulator device or when i create build with connected device. However, getting crashed for generic build with test flight.

Here is crash report.

{"app_name":"WashOn","timestamp":"2020-10-05 10:08:48.00 -0700","app_version":"1.2","slice_uuid":"e2d19995-e03c-3d92-823a-0c2eb5276114","adam_id":1534014889,"build_version":"4","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.washon.WashOn","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 14.2 (18B5061e)","incident_id":"46F34E11-C6D2-451D-9277-253D6EE02A45","name":"WashOn"}
Incident Identifier: 46F34E11-C6D2-451D-9277-253D6EE02A45
CrashReporter Key:   6c04358e480fe00b97cb90f6551da92d35bd586e
Hardware Model:      iPad11,3
Process:             WashOn [329]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/84295AEE-9CD3-4BC6-91CE-7738FB47803B/WashOn.app/WashOn
Identifier:          com.washon.WashOn
Version:             4 (1.2)
AppStoreTools:       12A7207
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.washon.WashOn [468]

Date/Time:           2020-10-05 10:08:48.3585 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-10-05 10:08:28.2235 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.2 (18B5061e)
Release Type:        Beta
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, <RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-create watchdog transgression: application<com.washon.WashOn>:329 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.81 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 47.840 (user 47.840, system 0.000), 40% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.032, 0% CPU" | ) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>
Triggered by Thread:  0

Crash report apple response : https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple124/v4/8e/26/eb/8e26eb51-0cad-6c5a-270f-f76e4df1687f/attachment.crashlog-46F34E11-C6D2-451D-9277-253D6EE02A45.txt?accessKey=1603731196_3150586006139646702_zjr3oMBt8U7mpxvjjKIhYgkh4RHscho2Bf4rRBEBc%2F85VEAadvnuW1d8j03sWD24DZP2hmsJEBUdJZBJ5YN8Ty56%2BmbtthKFG5B0exd6q%2B3i5CWO%2FGqTjbNOCxbpbTBTErkpg4R%2FfSHwcRub4VVqpysVFY3s%2FzgXLIrCaImyuVIVrBPO2dVlVuTms7OuSlfhiIp8IZlB1wxtjtzANZEQOXBJg%2B6v7KvyqAzRTaDEoHw%3D

Comment: Excuse me I seem to have the same problem than you but the link you provided doesn't work, did you solve it?

Comment: Any progress here?